# How to change imageView in header cell after pick a photo from imagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a custom header cell in a collection view. Below is how I set my image from url in my header

```
    let profileImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 42
    image.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return image
}()

    var userInfo: CauNguyenUserInfoModel?{
    didSet{
        if let profileImageUrl = userInfo?.profileImageUrl {
            if let imageUrl = URL(string: profileImageUrl) {
                profileImage.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "default_avatar"), options: [.continueInBackground, .progressiveDownload], completed: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then use protocol and delegation to pass action from a button in my header class to collection view class and using UIImagePickController to select different image from user device

This is func from my collection View controller not from header class

```
 func changeProfileImageBtnPressed() {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and using this function to get image file

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        print(editedImage)
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My question is after user select an image from his device and I have the image file, how do I change the image in my header class with that image? I put picker func in my collection view controller.

Comment: Where you put the imagePicker code ??

Comment: In my collection view controller not in header class

Comment: implemented viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind  ???

Comment: ofcourse I have it

Comment: Why not access the imageView directly inside the method and set the current image if exists from the picker by reloading the collection after you pick the image ?

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do but I don't know how to pass back the image to custom header class

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    var newImage: UIImage?
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        newImage = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        newImage = originalImage
    }
    imageView.image = image
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: how do I pass back the image to header class?

Comment: the imageView is in my custom header class not in collection View controller.

Comment: Either pass an escaping [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) into the class containing the image picker code or create a delegate from a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) that passes it back. The easiest and worst option would be to create a weak reference to the imageView inside of the header class and use the weak reference to assign it its image.